# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL with Java

Tags: java, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've been trying for days and have gotten nowhere. I am trying to connect to my MySQL database through a JavaFX program I'm building, without requiring me to whitelist every IP that attempts to connect. The GCP support team has replied to me once but completely misinterpreted the issue (gave examples of logs that only occurred after I whitelisted my own IP to test the other aspects of my program).

​

I found instructions at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#java, and pasted the following code into my main method (substituting the appropriate values for databaseName, instanceConnectionName, username, and password):

```
String jdbcUrl = String.format(
"jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s"
+ "&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false",
databaseName,
instanceConnectionName);

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, 
password);
```

​

I then enabled the Cloud API and, to the best of my knowledge, installed and authenticated the Cloud SDK, as directed. Yet despite all of that, I still cannot connect to the instance without a whitelisted IP address, even though the documentation says this is the workaround for that. Does anyone see an issue with how I'm attempting to connect or know how to make this work?

Comment: Have you followed the steps in this [document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory)? This link has more detailed instructions. Also make sure you add the Cloud SQL Socket Factory as a dependency in your project. For a more complete example, take a look at [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/master/examples/compute-engine/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/sql/mysql/example/ListTables.java). If you still have problems after following those links can you share the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

There are some more detailed instructions in the README for the [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) of the project.

Some potential tripping points:

1. Use [Application Default Credentials](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#authentication) to provide credentials to the factory.
2. Make sure you have the `Cloud SQL API` enabled to your project (and if you are using a service account, make sure to have the `Cloud SQL Client` role added to it).
3. Add the library as a [dependency](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#add-library-as-a-dependency) in your POM or gradlefile.
4. Make sure your firewall allows out on port 3307 to your Cloud SQL instance.