# ClassNotFoundException: Google Cloud SQL with MySQL/SocketFactory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect my Java code to a db I've created in Google Cloud SQL, but I'm getting ClassNotFound and SQLException errors: -

*java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql*

I'm also getting a NullPointerException in code, in the getAllFilms() method at the line below, which I'm assuming is because the code isn't making a db connection: -

*ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);*

Things I've done so far: -

- Tested the Google Cloud SQL db credentials, through a client connection
- Reviewed related posts, particularly [this one][1]
- Been through the Google documentation
- Added MySQL and Socket Factory Connector(j8) JARs to my project dependencies

Unfortunately I'm still unable to resolve. Hopefully someone can help. I've attached my Java code below. Thanks in advance...

```
Film oneFilm = null;
Connection googleSqlConnection = null;
Statement stmt = null;

String url = "jdbc:mysql:///<dbname>?<cloudSqlInstance>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.
mysql.SocketFactory&user=<user>&password=<pword>";

public FilmDAO() {
    }

    private void openConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Class.forName("com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        try {
            googleSqlConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            stmt = googleSqlConnection.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println(se);
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection() {
        try {
            googleSqlConnection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public ArrayList<Film> getAllFilms() {

        ArrayList<Film> allFilms = new ArrayList<>();

        openConnection(); 

        try {
            String selectSQL = "select * from films limit 50";
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);
            while (rs1.next()) {
                oneFilm = getNextFilm(rs1);
                allFilms.add(oneFilm);
            }

            stmt.close();
            closeConnection();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println(se);
        }

        return allFilms;
    }


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693679/connecting-to-google-cloud-sql-with-java
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the Cloud SQL JDBC SocketFactory and `mysql-connector-java` to your `pom.xml`?